# Inner join using distinct on

Tags: postgresql

```
create table emp
(
   emp_id serial primary key,
   emp_no integer,
   emp_ref_no character varying(15),
   emp_class character varying(15),
   created_at timestamp,
   created_by character varying(20)
);

create table emp_detail
(
   emp_detail_id serial primary key,
   emp_id integer,
   class_no integer,
   col1 JSONB,
   col2 JSONB,
   col3 JSONB,
   created_at timestamp without time zone default now(),
   created_by character varying(20),
   constraint con_fk foreign key(emp_id) references emp(emp_id)
 );

INSERT INTO emp(
            emp_no, emp_ref_no, emp_class, created_by)
    VALUES ('548251', '2QcW', 'abc', 'Nik');

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '2018-05-04 11:00:00', 
            'Nik'); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '2018-04-04 11:00:00', 
            'Nik'); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '2018-05-10 11:00:00', 
            'Nik');

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at, 
            created_by)
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '2018-02-01 11:00:00', 
            'Nik');
```

I want to display corresponding emp_id, emp_no, emp_ref_no along with all the columns of emp_detail table. Emp_detail table should be group by class no and should only show the record which has max (created_at)
I am trying to use distinct on but does not give desired result

```
select e.emp_id, e.emp_no, e.emp_ref_no, ed.* from emp e inner join emp_detail ed on e.emp_id=ed.emp_id
where emp_detail_id in(select distinct on (ed.class_no) ed.emp_detail_id
from emp_detail ed
order by ed.class_no, created_at desc) and e.emp_no=548251;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

```
|emp_id|emp_no|emp_ref_no|emp_detail_id|emp_id|class_no|col1  |col2  |col3  |created_at         |created_by|
|------|------|----------|-------------|------|--------|------|------|------|-------------------|----------|
|     1|548251|2QcW      |            1|     1|       1|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|2018-05-04 11:00:00|Nik       |
|     1|548251|2QcW      |            3|     1|       2|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|2018-05-10 11:00:00|Nik       |
```

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ff0874f780a3da4fbd9ba7f5aacc8be5)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ed.class_no)
    e.emp_id, e.emp_no, e.emp_ref_no, ed.*
FROM 
    emp_detail ed
JOIN emp e ON e.emp_id = ed.emp_id
ORDER BY ed.class_no, ed.created_at DESC
```

If you want to use `DISTINCT ON (any group)` you have to order by this group and after that you need to define the order within these groups. So your groups are the `class_no` and the criteria to group row within the `class_no` is the `created_at` timestamp. So your `ORDER BY` clause is `(class_no, created_at DESC)`. Then `DISTINCT ON` filters out exactly the first row of each ordered group, in that case the last recent created one is the first.

Comment: Is it possible to apply DISTINCT ON on candidate key?

Comment: You mean DISTINCT ON (e.emp_id)?

Comment: There are instances where emp_no and emp_ref no are unique and needs to be displayed in output and for that corresponding emp_detail needs to be displayed

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question for demonstrating

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403420/inner-join-on-multiple-tables-using-distinct-on

I have raised new question.

Comment: Please do not open a second question for that. It's nearly the same thing just a join more. and please always add a the expected output. Please minimize your examples. there are many columns we do not need.