# Join on multiple tables using distinct on

Tags: postgresql, join, distinct-on

```
  create table emp
(
   emp_id serial primary key,
   emp_no integer,
   emp_ref_no character varying(15),
   emp_class character varying(15)
);

create table emp_detail
(
   emp_detail_id serial primary key,
   emp_id integer,
   class_no integer,
   created_at timestamp without time zone,
   constraint con_fk foreign key(emp_id) references emp(emp_id)
 );

create table class_detail
(
class_id serial primary key,
emp_id integer,
class_no integer,
col1 JSONB,
created_at timestamp without time zone default now(),
constraint cd_fk foreign key(emp_id) references emp(emp_id)
);


INSERT INTO emp(
            emp_no, emp_ref_no, emp_class)
    VALUES ('548251', '2QcW', 'abc' );

INSERT INTO emp(
            emp_no, emp_ref_no, emp_class)
    VALUES ('548251', '2FQx', 'abc');

INSERT INTO emp(
            emp_no, emp_ref_no, emp_class)
    VALUES ('548251', '2yz', 'abc');

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at
            )
    VALUES ( 1, 2, '2018-05-04 11:00:00'
            ); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at
            )
    VALUES ( 1, 1, '2018-04-04 11:00:00'
            ); 

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at
            )
    VALUES ( 2, 1, '2018-05-10 11:00:00' 
            );

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at 
            )
    VALUES ( 2, 2, '2018-02-01 11:00:00' 
            );

INSERT INTO emp_detail(
            emp_id, class_no, created_at
            )
    VALUES ( 3, 2, '2018-02-01 11:00:00'
            );

insert into class_detail(emp_id, class_no, col1, created_at) values(1,1,'{"Name":"Nik"}', '2018-02-01 10:00:00');

insert into class_detail(emp_id, class_no, col1, created_at) values(1,1,'{"Name":"Nik Anderson"}', '2018-03-01 10:00:00');

insert into class_detail(emp_id, class_no, col1, created_at) values(1,2,'{"Name":"James Anderson TST"}', '2018-03-15 10:00:00');

insert into class_detail(emp_id, class_no, col1, created_at) values(1,2,'{"Name":"Tim Paine ST"}', '2018-04-01 10:00:00');
```

I want to display corresponding emp_id, emp_no, emp_ref_no, class_no(the latest one from emp_detail table based on created at)along with all the columns of class_detail table. Class_detail table should show the latest corresponding record of the class no

The expected output which I would like to see is something like below :-

```
emp id | emp_no | emp_ref_no |  class_no | class_id  |  class.col1          | class.created_at | class.created_by
1      | 548251 |  2QcW      |    2      |    4      |{"Name":"Tim Paine ST"}|2018-04-01 10:00:00| NUlL
2      | 548251 |  2FQx      |    1      |    2      |{"Name":"Nik Anderson"}|2018-03-01 10:00:00| NULL
3      | 548251 |  2yz       |    2      |    4      |{"Name":"Tim Paine ST"}|2018-04-01 10:00:00| NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join using distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397504/inner-join-using-distinct-on)

Comment: Nope, here the requirement is different.

Comment: Please add expected output and minimize your example (there are many unneeded columns for example.)

Comment: I have made changes as per your suggestions. @S-Man

Comment: It is still no minimal data set. And your script is not working. Please fix your sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a64d93bd357be6cdc377a56294a1710d

Comment: Fixed the script and made the data minimal.. Could you please help me on this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comments: It is exactly the same thing as in [Inner join using distinct on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397504/inner-join-using-distinct-on). You simply have to add another join and another `ORDER BY` group (`cd.created_at DESC`)

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=81b0cb6752762f71310967d46ba30aa5)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ed.emp_id)
    e.emp_id, e.emp_no, e.emp_ref_no, ed.class_no, cd.*
FROM 
    emp_detail ed
JOIN emp e ON e.emp_id = ed.emp_id
JOIN class_detail cd ON ed.class_no = cd.class_no
ORDER BY ed.emp_id, ed.created_at DESC, cd.created_at DESC
```

**Note**: I am not sure what the `emp_id` column in `class_detail` is for. It seems not well designed (this is also because it is always `1` in your example.) You should check whether you really need it.